# How to set manual approval for a stage in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some stages and jobs linked to it.

```
install-rpm:
  stage: deployrpm
  allow_failure: true
  extends:
   - .iftestawsdeploy
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
      terraform_version: 1.1.7
      terragrunt_version: 0.36.6
      kubectl_version: 1.21.11
  before_script:
    - *install_dependencies
    - *install_myproject_rpm
  script:
    - *run_myproject_deploy
    - exit 0
  after_script:
    - *forward_myproject_resources
    - ls dist1
    - exit 0
  artifacts:
   paths:
    - ./dist1
  tags:
    - ec2runner

cleanup-aws:
  stage: cleanup
  allow_failure: true
  extends:
   - .iftestawsdeploy
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
      terraform_version: 1.1.7
      terragrunt_version: 0.36.6
      kubectl_version: 1.21.11
  before_script:
    - *install_dependencies
    - *install_myproject_rpm
    - *use_myproject_resources
  script:
    - *teardown_myproject
  after_script:
    - *nuke_SUB_AWS_resources
  tags:
    - dev
```

I want to set an option before the job cleanupaws above or the cleanup stage so that when previous stages completed, this job/stage should wait till someone clicks on continue or approve button.
So that, we can do our R&D tasks if any failure in deployment and later we can resume cleanup tasks.
Please suggest how to setup that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stage that preceeds the stage you want to be started manually and create a single manual job in that stage.

```yaml
stages:
  # ...
  - cleanup_approval
  - cleanup

manual_cleanup:
  # this job must be run manually to allow cleanup stage to run
  stage: cleanup_approval
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo noop
  allow_failure: false

cleanup-aws:
  stage: cleanup
  # runs after `manual_cleanup` job in the previous stage has been manually run
  # ...
```

Comment: what is the allow_failure for here?

Comment: @UdayKiranReddy when a job specifies `when: manual` it implies `allow_failure: true` which would allow subsequent stages to start even if the job is not run. Setting `allow_failure: false` helps ensure that the job has the default behavior -- that it must run and succeed before the following stages run.

Comment: what if I want to run even if the stage failed but should not start the subsequent jobs until it is success/failed?

Comment: @UdayKiranReddy in the above case, the job should always succeed because all it is doing is calling `echo`. If you did put some meaningful script in there, you could adjust the script to make sure it always exits successfully or use something like [`allow_failure:exit_codes: [1]`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failureexit_codes)